# CodeIgniter session cookie domain

Tags: php, codeigniter

It appears with the following cookie settings below, that cookies are set for the entire domain. For example if I was on http://subdomain.domain.com the cookie would be set for subdomain.domain.com if I was on domain.com the cookie would be set for domain.com.

If the cookie is set for subdomain.domain.com that does that mean subdomain2.domain.com cannot access a cookie from subdomain.domain.com?

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix' = Set a prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain' = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'   =  Typically will be a forward slash
|
*/
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Domain specific cookies are only accesible on that domain. Use ".domain.com" as your cookie domain to be able to use it across all subdomains and main domain.

Comment: It doesn't seams to work properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853783/codigniter-share-session-with-subdomain-sess-time-to-update

Answer (score -2):

When using several codeigniter applications on subdomains it is also important to set the same `$config[‘encryption_key’]`.