# Error in using common session for codeigniter driven subdomains

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, subdomain

I have some codeigniter driven sub-domains and using native codeigniter session library. There is a sub-domain that creates and updates the session and other sub-domain has to share the session. I am not able to share the session among other sub-domains. I have changed the config parameter in **application/config.php**

```
$config['cookie_domain']    = "example.com";
```

but it's not working.

Comment: try adding "www." in front of the domain.

Comment: Direct dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783595/codeigniter-session-cookie-domain  And after reading comments, still a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881092/subdomain-overwiting-codeigniter-session Please look around before asking questions, a google of "cookie subdomains codeigniter" would have found you loads of examples here and abroad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a dot at the beginning: `$config['cookie_domain']    = ".example.com";`

Comment: I tried by adding dot at the beginning but it didn't worked. Actually i was using different encryption key for sub-domains.

    $config['encryption_key'] = "keyvalue";
Corrected the encryption key and solved the problem, anyway thanks for the help...

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer.. because in relation to what you asked, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem.

Adding ".example.com" to cookie_domain didn't work for me. I was using different encryption keys (`$config['encryption_key']`) for both subdomains too.

When they were made the same, the session was then available across both subdomains.